# Regular Expression for relational operators and quoted values

Tags: regex

I have an sql query. I want to allow user to modify only relational operators or values within single quotes

My input string is.

```
Select * from defect where Quantity < '9' and Date <= curdate() and Date >=
date_sub(curdate(), interval '3' month)
```

I am trying following patterns to match the above string as it is. I also tried ^ at beginning and $ at end. But no positive result in any case

```
1. Select * from defect where Quantity [<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)|(like)] '.*' and
Date [<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)|(!=)|(like)] curdate() and Date [<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)
|(!=)|(like)] date_sub(curdate(), interval '.*' month)

2. Select * from defect where Quantity (<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)|(like)) '.*' and
Date (<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)|(!=)|(like)) curdate() and Date (<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)
|(!=)|(like)) date_sub(curdate(), interval '.*' month)
```

**Update** Need guidance why my patterns are not matching my input string. What could be the mistake?

Comment: Any attempt to "censor" SQL statements like that is usually a bad idea. The risk to make a mistake and allow something unexpected is just too big. I would instead suggest you to build the statements in your program. What's the context in which this is used?

Comment: @Philipp my database user asks me for the report of a certain time period, for certain specific values. I prepare that report using sql and save this sq to database against the report name. I am displaying all prepared queries for reports and allowing to change the values and operators only. I am doing this validation just because of security. I know the value within quotes can not do any thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more problems: You're using square brackets incorrectly:

```
[<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)|(like)]
```

means "one character out of the following: `<>()|=eikl`".

Use parentheses instead of brackets, and group sensibly:

```
([<>=]|[<>]=|like)
```

Also, you should be more specific: Use `'[^']*'` instead of `'.*'`.

Finally, if you want to match a literal parenthesis, you need to escape it in your regex:

```
date_sub\(curdate\(\), interval '[^']*' month\)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim Pietzcker. I am very impressed form you. I have a very important question about regular expressions. Already written. Can I post that right now? I need a general guide about Regex.

Comment: @Sami: Sure, just open another question.

Comment: I have opened. It may seem some stupid but please help me to improve that (By the way it was my first question on forum and I was banned and had to delete it, later on some how i was allowed to keep questioning on SO). Other than Regex I just ask questions mostly just for the ease. Only Regex is the problem which is too tough for me without forum :)

Comment: You should replace all whitespace in the query with `\s+`, too.  Currently it requires exactly one space between each pairs words, because that's how it is in the sample query you @Sami) copied it from.  (With one exception: the "space" before `date_sub` is actually a linefeed, so your regex requires a linefeed there.)

Comment: @AlanMoore you are right. But I am already facilitating user a lot. user is supposed to change nothing except the relational operators and values. It is obviously good to accommodate white spaces and more but I needed just those two things. You may have a look at the comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

My pattern 1 was alright just I had to put a backslash before '*' as it has special meanings in Regex. Backslash makes it a normal character

```
Select \* from defect where Quantity [<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)|(like)] '.*' and
Date [<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)|(!=)|(like)] curdate() and Date [<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)
|(!=)|(like)] date_sub(curdate(), interval '.*' month)
```

It was an easy question. I knew that rule already, but could sort it out after hours.

**Correction** Replaced square brackets`[]` with parenthesis`()` and backslash is put before constant parenthesis `\(` and `\)`

```
Select \* from defect where Quantity (<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)|(like)) '.*' and
Date (<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)|(!=)|(like)) curdate\(\) and Date (<|(>)|(=)|(<=)|(>=)
|(!=)|(like)) date_sub\(curdate\(\), interval '.*' month\)
```

Comment: // lastQury is fetched from database and pasted into qurybox. Where user can modify and before submit i make a pattern like

`string pat = lastQury; 
string ops = " (<|>|=|<=|>=|like) ";
pat = pat.Replace(" <= ", ops);
pat = pat.Replace(" >= ", ops);
pat = pat.Replace(" != ", ops);
pat = pat.Replace(" = ", ops);
pat = pat.Replace(" < ", ops);
pat = pat.Replace(" > ", ops);
pat = pat.Replace(" like ", ops);
pat = pat.Replace("(", @"\(");
pat = pat.Replace(")", @"\)");
pat = pat.Replace("*", @"\*");
pat = Regex.Replace(pat, "'[^']*'", "'.*'");` Before submit i test quryBox.Text with this paatern

Comment: Actually i am making pattern from a string by replacing operators and values within quotes with wildcards. Other things remain fixed. Then input string is allowed to be changed but only two type of changes are allowed. As after changed it is compared (on submit) with pattern made from it before changes in it. If it matches it is ok otherwise user have option to correct it or restore original string