# How to search(google) for Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

**For me it is the most important question about Regex, may be for some others too.**

I rarely use regular expressions. But whenever I have to tackle with a bit complex regular expression i find even hard to find the words for search.

And except regex I can not think any other thing in programming for which I could be stuck to search. And lot of problems of those domains, where your knowledge/skills are too little are solved easily by little search. But unable to do this thing in case of regex

For example I have a valid expression

```
Select * from sale  where Quantity < '10'  and Date <= curdate() and
Date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 3 month)
```

I have allowed user to modify this query but after modification I want to verify that user has chnaged nothing except relational operators and values following the relation operators. Regex would be something like

```
Select .+ from sale  where Quantity [<|>|=|(<=)|(>=)] .+  and Date 
[<|>|=|(<=)|(>=)] .+ and Date [<|>|=|(<=)|(>=)] (string not containing any join)
```

This specific question is already solved. Actual question is general about Regex.

I can think only two solutions for problems like this

1. To have a good knowledge/skills/concepts of regular expression
2. Ask on forum.

In all other cases I usually find help from search without reading tutorials etc, except some very typical/unique/new type of technique. But **search does not seem solid solution in case of regular expressions because they are mostly unique. Is it? How?**

It does not mean I am against reading tutorials. I do myself and perhaps more for Regex than other things (Because we had not read them enough in our course) but still face problems

Comment: Please comment on it before voting for close. I have this question for three months but unable to find any appropriate answer.

Comment: "This specific question is already solved." - not with that regex it isn't.  You *are* using the regex from [@Tim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12545540/20938) now, aren't you?

Comment: @AlanMoore Hopefully you would be aware of bit details of the scenario. Here the specific problem was not much concerned. I had this question before my specific problem solved so copy pasted it after Tim's encouragement. Here the problem was that how could I inquire google or tutorials for that type of solution (If correct solution is necessary here I can update it. Should I?). You may have a look, all my questions other than regex are most likely be faced by many others. Only a question like my last one about regex is too specific for me that is why I was asking for a general solution.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to make sure you got full value from that other question.  Saying the problem was solved while posting the original, broken regex *was* a little confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask questions about programming problems easily because you know the basic concepts: Loops, functions, lists, hashes, modules, strings, input, output, files - you know the basic vocabulary and therefore you know how to ask a programming question.

But you didn't get this knowledge from nothing - at one point you had to learn the basics. This is easy to forget because you take them for granted.

With regular expressions, there are many new concepts to learn, a new vocabulary. Suddenly, there are new words like groups, alternations, anchors, lazy and greedy quantifiers, lookaround, atomic grouping, captures and much more...and you won't get around learning that new vocabulary so you can ask meaningful questions.

It's not that difficult to get yourself acquainted with the basic concepts. Use a decent tutorial (http://www.regular-expressions.info), play with regexes in your favorite language, use online regex testers...Personally, I learned nearly everything I know about regexes from using RegexBuddy on a daily basis. And from StackOverflow.

You can ask basic regex questions here, there are lots of them everyday. And usually only those get downvoted where it's obvious the poster hasn't put a shred of effort into them.

Comment: Thaks sir. I am satisfied and encouraged with the answer. Although i use to put a question after healthy effort and try to present my effort too. Still I had been feeling me burden on SO while asking a question whose solution would most likely help only me. Because others have almost no chance to face same problem and it has been the case, only with Regex, not otherwise. Now I have got some confident, some better idea to ask and some general guide to learn Regex in a better effective way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, following your reasoning, one could argue that it's not possible to search for SQL expressions, because database schemas are unique, so there would be no hits. Yet it practice it works well.

You have to search for the concepts and ideas, and not for an actual solutions for a very specific problem.

Of course you have to know the *basics*. If you can't *name* the things you're looking for, it's implossible to search for them.

For your example here's a practical search: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=regexp+match+either+or First hit: "Regex Tutorial - Alternation with The Vertical Bar"

Comment: Sorry sql quesry was just an example input string question is just about Regex. Nothing to do with sql or databases. My that problem is already solved. Remaining part of your answer is seems good.

Comment: I know SQL was just an example. And that's what I did too. Just used it as an example.

Comment: Like the way of your answering and your answer too. If possible i would have awarded +2 :). I have to analyze the answers before accepting :)

Answer (score 1):

Three things you can do:

1. Have a Regex cheatsheet for your specific flavor of regex open in front of you.
2. Use a tool to give you instant feedback and "evolve" the expression rather than trying to construct it all at once.  I use [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) cuz, it's free.
3. Write your own test rig to experiment with different features.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice answer. Will follow the instructions and analyze the answers.